# What is the subject of "行ってくれると言ってました"?

Tags: giving-and-receiving

Context:

> 今日は会社に出社して、退勤後新居の鍵を受け取りに不動産屋さんへ行きました。そのまま夜ご飯を食べて帰りました。イケメンの不動産屋さんは大事な試験が終わった10月末以降にご飯に**行ってくれると言ってました**。楽しみです！

Is the subject of "ご飯に行ってくれる" same as the subject of "と言ってました"?

What are these subjects? Are them "不動産屋さん" both?

Does "行ってくれる" mean "invite me to" actually？

Comment: 状況がいまいちつかめないんですが・・・この人、不動産屋さんのおにいちゃんを食事に誘ったんですかね？

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about the context, the situation is that the author is a girl and she has a crush on the employee of the real estate agent, and it seems that they have agreed to have dinner together in this text, but I don't quite understand the granting relationship in "行ってくれると言ってました" and who the subject is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, イケメンの不動産屋さん is the subject of both ご飯に行ってくれる and 言ってました.

ご飯に行ってくれる literally means "(will) go eat (for me)" and you should assume 私と "with me" omitted here. However, the person who invited the other is most likely the girl and not 不動産屋さん. This is because if the situation is reversed (不動産屋さん invited the girl), one would write ご飯に連れて行ってくれる "(will) take (me) to go eat (for me)" instead.

Comment: Thanks!  Now I know that "ご飯に行ってくれる" is something that "不動産屋さん" said to the authoress, and the fact is that the authoress invited "不動産屋さん" to dinner. So may I ask what "ご飯に行ってくれる" actually means?

Comment: @Theseus ご飯に行ってくれる is not the exact phrase that the 不動産屋さん said to her, but it's more like "He will do me a favor of going for dinner (with me)", as in 「行ってくれると言っていた」"He said that he would go / that he would do me a favor of going." Vてくれる means "(someone) does me a favor of doing V", cf. Vてあげる means "I do (someone) a favor of doing V". So from the 不動産屋さん's standpoint it'd be 「ご飯に行ってあげる」"I will do you a favor of going for dinner (with you)." Does this make sense?

Comment: @chocolate♦ Thanks! I think this is a very detailed explanation about " Vてくれる", I got it.